# Как визуализировать большое кол-во данных matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня 213 значений по x и по y и мне как-то надо визуализировать это, чтобы все было понятно. Сейчас у меня все сбито в кучу. Значение по x это даты в формате DD/MM/YY[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

plt.plot(x, y) строил так
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку свой код вы не сочли нужным нам приводить, а гадать дело неблагодарное - принимайте и ответ не в виде готового программного решения, а в виде общего совета:
У вас два пути:

- Разворот меток осей на 90 градусов (параметр rotation=45 или rotation=90 - по вкусу);
- Вывод не всех, а только некоторого количества меток (например -  каждую десятую). Тут придется разобраться в пакетом matplotlib.ticker.

Для более тонкой настройки  используйте метод tick_params(), позволяющий изменять, в том числе, и размер подписей и их шрифт и много чего еще.